# Do I need to connect Firebase to Azure Notification Hub?

Tags: azure, firebase, asp.net-core, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I see that I can either connect directly (through Rest HTTP requests) to Google Firebase API but I can also connect it to Azure Notification Hub. I also understand that Firebase is free while Azure isn't.

Can you kindly describe what is the benefit of connecting Firebase to Azure rather than directly connecting to Google's API (if any)?

I'm using ASP.Net Core MVC as my backend.
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are doing one push platform only (Firebase in your case) and only considering basic scenarios, then there's not much difference between using it directly or via Notification Hubs (NH).

However, NH provides you with a set of really powerful features:

- Cross-platform SDKs to allow [device registrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530747.aspx) from all major OSes and a unified way of sending pushes no matter which platform they are on
- A feature that is unique across similar services is [tagging and routing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530749.aspx)
- [Templating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530748.aspx)
- Basic or [extended telemetry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt608135.aspx)

And some other features.

So, in short, yes you can do everything that NH does by yourself. It's just you'll spend a lot of time (and money on resources required to run it) while doing it. And this is an out of the box solution that has been tested through years and is used by some of the largest products on the market.